# How to interpret the attempt information from Hydra

Tags: password-cracking, hydra

I was performing a Hydra attack on my TP-Link router and for that I prepared a passwords.txt  file with 288 passwords.

```
hydra -l webadmin -P test_creds/passwords.txt xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ftp
```

A minute after I set Hydra off it showed me the following message:

```
[STATUS] 405.00 tries/min, 405 tries in 00:01h, 18446744073709551500 todo in 5124095576030430:60h
```

What I don't understand is what `405 tries in 00:01h` and `18446744073709551500 todo in 5124095576030430:60h` mean. As I understand it, Hydra is telling me that it's about to make 5124095576030430 login attempts in 60 hours. But mathematically speaking when you combine 288 passwords with 1 username you get a total of `288 * 1` credentials and if, as shown in it's first output, it is attempting `405.00 tries/min` it should only take around 43 seconds to try all of them. Now, that's not what's happening. So what do those numbers mean?

Comment: have you tried: `hydra -l webadmin -P test_creds/passwords.txt ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` ?

Comment: I did what you said and this was the first output `[STATUS] 409.00 tries/min, 409 tries in 00:01h, 18446744073709551496 todo in 5124095576030430:60h, 16 active`

Comment: I'm trying to sort out why it wants to test more than 288 combinations. My next guess is that the passwords.txt that you want it to use is not the file that it is picking up. Try moving the passwords.txt file to your cwd and changing your command to match?

Comment: Yeah, that is the output I got when I ran the command from the directory where `passwords.txt` is in

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the output.

`5124095576030430:60h` is not a ratio of tries to the number of hours. That's the number of hours it is going to take.

The number of tries is plainly explained:

`18446744073709551500` in `5124095576030430:60h`

If you are expecting only 288 attempts, then it looks like you have misconfigured your command.